# Burpsuite proxy troubleshoot issue

Tags: ios, mobile, proxy, penetration-testing, burp

I am working on mobile pentests currently. At first, using my home network I was able to intercept traffic on burpsuite for both iOS and Android versions of “Test App”. Then the next day, I still am able to intercept traffic but the behaviour of this “Test App” for both iOS and Android seem like it has certificate pinning as I was just stuck on the pre-auth page and getting errors when trying to log in. Without proxy though I am still able to login OK and proceed with the app normally so I don’t think my home network got blacklisted? (For context, the binaries does not have any certificate pinning).

But when I tried to change my network to my mobile hotspot, I could intercept the traffic and app behaves normally again.

Anyone encountered the same previously? Any ideas on what could be causing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This does seem odd. I would wager one of three things is happening here:

1. You accidentally left "Intercept" on in Burp Suite Proxy. This holds the response in Burp Suite until you click Forward, which would cause behavior very similar to what you are describing here. I have done this more times than I am willing to admit.
2. There was a temporary outage in the application's API. Not unheard of, especially if this is an unreleased app.
3. There is some sort of issue on your home network, but this is unlikely. Maybe two devices have the same static IP address?

It's hard to say exactly what the issue might be based on the information you provided, but hopefully this was helpful, or at least gives you a place to start!